# MySQL auto increment column on update to unique value

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I have a table that looks something like:

```
name: posts
columns: 
- id
- sequence_id
- text
- like_count
```

The ID is a standard auto-incremented unique integer index.

The sequence ID should be similar — it is also a unique integer index.

The difference is that I want to increment it to the new maximum value in the table on *update or insert* not just insert.

Currently I accomplish this with a Redis counter that I increment before inserting into the database.

I’d like to drop the Redis dependency, though, and do this with purely MySQL if possible.

One option I thought of was creating a post_updates table which just has an auto-incrementing ID which I use the same way but this feels worse.

Another option is doing a full column scan to do max(sequence_id) + 1 but that isn’t really scalable and it would have race conditions.

Are there some better options I’m not aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a solution in the manual to [simulate a sequence object in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id):

```
CREATE TABLE sequence (id INT NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO sequence VALUES (0);
```

The `sequence` table doesn't need an auto-increment itself, and it stores only one row.

When you are ready to increment your sequence_id in the table you describe, you first update the sequence value in the following manner:

```
UPDATE sequence SET id = LAST_INSERT_ID(id+1);
```

Now you can use that value when inserting/updating your table:

```
INSERT INTO posts SET sequence_id = LAST_INSERT_ID(), text = '...';
```

or

```
UPDATE posts SET sequence_id = LAST_INSERT_ID(), like_count = like_count+1;
```

Note that this is a little bit more heavy than an auto-increment, because updating the sequence table creates a row lock, not just an auto-increment lock. This could put an upper limit on the rate of traffic, because many concurrent clients trying to access this table would queue up on each other.

If you want a very high-throughput solution, I'd recommend to continue using Redis.

Comment: Hmm that still requires locking which isn't ideal. In my case I guess it's not strictly necessary that the sequence IDs be unique as long as they:
a) only ever increase
b) the likelihood of two values having the same sequence ID is small
I wonder if it's possible to sidestep the issue by using a unix timestamp + a random number.

Comment: I understood your question to be about unique values. If you just want a timestamp, then feel free to do that.

Comment: It's not just a timestamp because it's important to avoid a scenario where multiple items updated in the same transaction have the same sequence ID. If it was just a timestamp there could be collisions (even with microsecond precision). But I'm thinking if I bitshift the unix microseconds up and pad with a few random bits that should probably be sufficient.

Comment: As I said, feel free to do that. It won't be guaranteed unique, but you said that isn't strictly necessary to you.